# How to get a property's value from an other class object in a list

Tags: c#, class

I'm learning C# and it's not clear for me how to access a property in a `foreach` loop of `FieldsList` class. It was not accessible. I'm try to get a string concatenation with name of `FieldData`.

What's wrong?

```
namespace MyNamesp
{
    public class FldData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Type FldType { get; set; }

        public FldData() { }

        public FldData(string name, Type fldType)
        {
            Name = name;
            FldType = fldType;
        }
    }


    class FieldsList<FldData> : List<FldData>
    {
        public int NumField { get { return this.Count; }  }
        public string QryFieldList()
         {

           string _QryFieldList = "";

            foreach(FldData fld in this)
            {
                _QryFieldList += fld.Name +",";  //Fld.Name is not accessible 
            }

            return _QryFieldList;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the `FieldsList` class shouldn't have a generic type argument,
just declare it as here below.

When defined as `FieldsList<FldData>`, the `FldData` part is considered as the **generic type argument** which is not the `FldData` class, although both names are similar.

```
class FieldsList : List<FldData>
{
    public int NumField { get { return this.Count; } }
    public string QryFieldList()
    {

        string _QryFieldList = "";

        foreach (FldData fld in this)
        {
            _QryFieldList += fld.Name + ",";
        }

        return _QryFieldList;
    }
}
```